# VS Designer and constructors with parameters

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio

I have a custom control `MyControl`. Has a parameterless constructor (`Sub New()` in VB).

I place that control in a WinForm.

No problems.

Now, want a parameter in that constructor. `Sub New(flag as Boolean)`

How should I deal with VS designer in that case, in order to be able to open that form in Designer?

I did in myForm the following

```
  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    Me.MyControl_1 = New MyControl(True)
    Me.InitializeComponent()
```

but the Designer says:

> The variable 'MyControl_1' is either
>   undeclared or was never assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designer requires a parameterless constructor for visual components.  Even adding an overloaded constructor to a user control will break the designer.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784303/c-usercontrol-constructor-with-parameters) question for more information.

Comment: yeah. I understand. But I can't use properties, because I have a control "mode" that can't be changed after its creation. (like readonly one). So I can't and wouldn't use properties. I need this "mode" be set only once, as earlier as possible. So I search a workaround.

Comment: an overloaded constructor does NOT break the designer, as long as there is also a parameterless constructor

Answer (score 1):

Modify to this

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    Me.InitializeComponent()
    Me.MyControl_1 = New MyControl(True)
```

Let designer initialize the cotrol before you use it. Problem is not with your control, problem is you are not using at right place.

Comment: I am afraid that if I'll reinitialize it after, I will loose it from its containers.

Comment: and. I loose all the designer parameters

Comment: In that case, why not simply have a method which will do all what you trying to do in ctor. And call it after InitializeComponent