# Inherit from a 'Form' which has parameters

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, inheritance, constructor

I have a Form named `ScanFolder`, and I need another Form, that needs to be very similar to `ScanFolder`, so I decided to use [form inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984432%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). But there seems to be some misunderstanding with the constructor.

`ScanFolder` looks like:

```
public partial class ScanFolder : Form
{
    public ScanFolder(MainForm parent, bool[] autoModes, GlobalMethods GMethodsClass)
    {
        //Doing something with parameters
    }
}
```

I tried to inherit `Form` like this:

```
public partial class Arch2 : ScanFolder
{
}
```

But I get warning Constructor on type 'mhmm.ScanFolder' not found, and also there is an error on `Arch2` Form edit mode, where I see a call stack error.

So I tried something like this:

```
public partial class Arch2 : ScanFolder
{
    public Arch2(MainForm parent, bool[] autoModes, GlobalMethods GMethodsClass)
        : base(parent, autoModes, GMethodsClass)
    {
    }
}
```

But it is still the same.

As you can see, I clearly don't have any idea what I'm doing. What I'm trying to achieve is getting `Arch2` to look the same as `ScanFolder`, so I can see it in designer view and also override some methods or event handlers.

Comment: Even if you get this working, you can't display a form in the Designer if it does not have a default constructor (meaning one that does not accept any parameters).

Comment: So if I get rid of all parameters and find any other way to use them in Form, I will be able to see my inherited form in design view?

Comment: you can add another method in ScanFolder to init the params InitParams(MainForm parent, bool[] autoModes, GlobalMethods GMethodsClass) and leave the constructor empty to handle the GUI only

Comment: Related: *['UserControl' constructor with parameters in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784303)*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To use the Forms designer, you will need to have a parameterless constructor:

```
public partial class ScanFolder : Form
{
    public ScanFolder()
    {
         InitializeComponent(); // added by VS
    }

    public ScanFolder(MainForm parent, bool[] autoModes, GlobalMethods gm)
       : this() // <-- important
    {
         // don't forget to call the parameterless ctor in each
         // of your ctor overloads
    }
}
```

Or, if you really need to have some init params, you can do it the other way around:

```
public partial class ScanFolder : Form
{
    public ScanFolder()
        : this(null, new bool[0], new GlobalMethods())
    {

    }

    public ScanFolder(MainForm parent, bool[] autoModes, GlobalMethods gm)
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // added by VS
        // other stuff
    }
}
```

I recommend the first approach, otherwise you need to pass some reasonable default parameters (I don't recommend passing a null parameter).

It seems that in some cases you will also have to restart Visual Studio after changing the class.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "call parameterless constructor"? Do i need to use ScanFolder() in each over overrided constructors in ScanFolder class? And what about inherited class? Should it look like my example in above post?

Comment: +1. This worked. However, I had to ***restart Visual Studio*** in order for the designer to work (coming from a state where I didn't have a parameterless constructor) - rebuilding the solution, etc. was not enough. Perhaps this information could be added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in parent form:

```
public partial class ScanFolder : Form
{
 public ScanFolder(MainForm parent, bool[] autoModes, GlobalMethods GMethodsClass)
  {
    //doing something with parameters
  }
}
```

and then in child form as:

```
public partial class ScanFolder : Form
{
  public ScanFolder(MainForm parent, bool[] autoModes, GlobalMethods GMethodsClass)
     : base(parent,autoModes,GMethodsClass)
  {
    //doing something with parameters
  }
}
```