# Understanding state in winform control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform user control.  In the constructor I instantiate a dependency.  It goes like

```
public IProvider provider {get;set;}

public MyUserControl()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   provider = new MockProvider();//for testing. Will pass into constructor eventually
}

private void MyUserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SomeModel model = new SomeModel(provider);//provider is null
   //do work
   model.InsertIntoDb();
}
```

I thought member state persisted until you explicitly call `Form.Close()`.  So why is the provider object null in the Load event?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - I just dropped it onto the Form in design view.  The Form's InitializeComponent() instantiates the user control.

Comment: I believe the Design View won't create instance.. not sure though. Does the error also occur at runtime?

Comment: I'm guessing your dev machine runs a 64-bit operating system.  You'll have to use the DesignMode property to prevent this code from running in design mode.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thanks for the tip hans.  That would be a great change for new app dev.  There's so much existing code right now that changing the way they do things would be a major headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InitializeComponent()` was setting the `Provider = null` inside of the "parent" form (the one instantiating the user control).  Turns out winforms [don't support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784303/c-sharp-usercontrol-constructor-with-parameters) parameterless constructors very well.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Make sure the new keyword is in the constructor of the control and something is instantiating that control somewhere.

Make sure the new is called before the second function. Maybe it is other way around in this one. State should persist.

Comment: The second function is the Load event.  The constructor does and certainly will be called before any of the objects events.