# Cross form communication

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program with two forms.
The second form, Form2 in which I want a few labels initialized with values from the main form.

The code:

```
public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Form1 mainForm = (Form1)this.Owner;
            lblName.Text = mainForm.gvRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            lblItemType.Text = mainForm.gvRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            lblLocation.Text = mainForm.gvRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        }
```

For some reason this does not work in the Form2() section, this.Owner is null. But if I was to place the code in an event method it works just fine.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Use the `Load` Event. The `Owner` is only initialized after you Show the form, which then in return raises the Load Event.

Comment: How do you show Form2? Anyway it's not a good practice doing it this way, You should use a better mechanism.

Comment: It doesn't get an Owner until the Show(owner) call.  That happens *after* the constructor runs.  The Load event would be the first place you can start poking for it.  Passing it as a constructor argument would be wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second form shouldn't need to even *know* about your main form in the first place.  Even if it did, it's an extremely bad idea to be reading into its internal controls.

Instead your second form should have public properties through which it can accept the data that your main form wants to provide to it, without exposing any of its internal controls, and the main form can set those properties using the data from its controls.  You could also potentially use parameters to the constructor instead, if you have just a bit of data, and that is the only time you need to provide it.

```
public class Form2
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return lblName.Text; }
        set { lblName.Text = value; }
    }
}

public class MainForm
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Form2 child = new Form2();
        child.Name = mainForm.gvRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        child.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense and it a lot cleaner too. Will code it like this, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This code is executed when the `Form2` form is *created*. The `Owner` isn't set yet (and, presumably, the data isn't present yet). If you put it in the `VisibleChanged` event handler - it will be executed when the `Owner` and data are (presumably) present.

Comment: @sd_dracula You're welcome. (As at the end of my answer - the best way is probably to have public properties in one of the `Form`s and access them from the other.)

Comment: yup that is the way I am doing it, gvRow is a public var in the mainForm

Comment: @sd_dracula oops. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Load` Event. The `Owner` is only initialized after you Show the form, which then in return raises the `Load` Event.

Answer (score 1):

Owner isn't set until the form is shown - i.e. in ShowDialog, not during the constructor.  You should pass the parent as a parameter in the constructor:

```
public Form2(Form1 mainForm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    lblName.Text = mainForm.gvRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    lblItemType.Text = mainForm.gvRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    lblLocation.Text = mainForm.gvRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the Owner is not initialized yet in the Form2 constructor, set your code in your Form2_Load event

Answer (score 0):

Use the Form.Show(IWin32Window) overload to pass the owner to the child form.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

[You need to set the Owner property yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

As an alternative you could pass a reference to Form1 to the Form2 constructor. In the code that opens Form2 you probably have something like this:

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
```

You could replace that with:

```
var form2 = new Form2(this);
form2.Show();
```

In Form2 you'd add a constructor overload:

```
public Form2(Form1 owningForm)
{
     InitializeComponent();
     Form1 mainForm = owningForm;
     lblName.Text = mainForm.gvRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
     lblItemType.Text = mainForm.gvRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
     lblLocation.Text = mainForm.gvRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
}
```

If different "owning forms" are possible you may need to define an interface instead of passing Form2.

Comment: Constructor Parameters in Windows Forms are against best practices. For every thing derived from `Control`.

Comment: If you have dependencies, injecting them with the constructor is clean . I don't really see why this would be different for a Form?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784303/usercontrol-constructor-with-parameters-in-c-sharp