# C# class string used on a another Form

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a little problem on my form Login when i Login, i want send my username on the string username in my class functions.

And when my Main Form is loaded i want this class functions get the username from my form login with my username

i have try something like this:

My form login:

```
public Functions FUNCTIONS = new Functions(); //for my class Functions

FUNCTIONS.Username = "Username123";
```

My class Functions:

```
  public class Functions
    {
       public string Username = ""; //empty
    }
```

and my Main form after login

```
public Functions FUNCTIONS = new FUNCTIONS();

  private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Welcome "+ FUNCTIONS.Username " to my application.");
   }
```

When my Main Form is loaded it's don't show the username string it's keep this empty, thanks for your time and your help for fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
public class Functions
{
    public static string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Also this way you dont need to initialize `Functions` with `new` keyword, `Functions.Username` would be enough

It would work because `static` keyword ensures that there is one instance of this peroperty for yor application lifetime. Also you could consider using singleton pattern with dependency injection, read more there :

https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton

Comment: Dependency injection in windows forms is far more trouble than it's worth, and IMO the 'singleton pattern' is best avoided. Just `static` is fine.

Comment: @stuartd in fact i had no expirience using DI in WinWorms so thanks for your point. Still, it is possible to use singletons without DI :)

Comment: What advantage does a singleton give over a static property in this use case? To me it adds unnecessary complexity just to access a value in multiple forms? Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @stuartd no, you right :) it is only another way to solve task and could be a point of interest later. But there's really no need to do smthn like this : https://gist.github.com/lolzballs/2152bc0f31ee0286b722 :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't create `new` 2nd time, `new` creates an another `Functions` instance. Pass to main Form the existing one instead and assign it to the field in main Form.

```cs
public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
    private Functions functions = new Functions();

    public LoginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        functions.Username = "Username123";
        new MainForm.Show(functions);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

```cs
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private Functions functions;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainForm(Functions f) : this()
    {
        functions = f;
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(functions.Username);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not to flexible, don't you think? I mean "What if we need Username on another form? Do we need to pass it via controller each time?"

Comment: Windows forms without paramterless constructors can't be loaded in the designer - _"Design decisions made regarding the way Windows Forms works more or less preclude parameterized .constructors for windows forms components."_ - [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784303/usercontrol-constructor-with-parameters-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @RomanKalinchuk I think that OP doesn't know what is `new` itself. On my perspective, I prefer powerful and flexible WPF+MVVM. ...and I hate Singleton. Almost no one can create and use it properly. Let it be a lesson how to pass an argument to the `.ctor`.

Comment: I mostly work with web (.Net Core) and my eyes are bleeding almost each time i see WinForms code :)))   Still, petterns (and singleton) are good when they are used well

Comment: Um, so after your last edit when the login form **loads** (`LoginForm_Load`) you set the username and show the main form? Which doesn't a) give the user a chance to log in or b) close the login form ..?

Comment: @stuartd it's not a complete code. Just an example how to pass an argument. It's reproducible, that's enough I guess.

Comment: @stuartd btw, fixed again.