# Make changes in inherited/child windows form (Visual Studio C#)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio, inheritance

I got an template windows form and an second one which is a child of the template.

But i cant change the content of my child form in the editor.

So I tried to add it manually in the designer file and it was shown in the editor but not when executed.

### Template

**.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;
        private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A1;

        [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
        [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int SendMessage(
            IntPtr hwnd,
            int wMsg,
            int wParam,
            int lParam);

        private void mdown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Rectangle rct = DisplayRectangle;
                if (rct.Contains(e.Location))
                {
                    ReleaseCapture();
                    SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**.Designer.cs**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Designervariable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Verwendete Ressourcen bereinigen.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">True, wenn verwaltete Ressourcen gelöscht werden sollen; andernfalls False.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Vom Windows Form-Designer generierter Code

        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Methode für die Designerunterstützung.
        /// Der Inhalt der Methode darf nicht mit dem Code-Editor geändert werden.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
            this.tableLayoutPanel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.pictureBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.tableLayoutPanel3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).BeginInit();
            this.tableLayoutPanel3.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // tableLayoutPanel1
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 1;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel2, 0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel3, 0, 2);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.panel2, 0, 1);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 3;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 12.82051F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 76.92308F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 10.25641F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 500);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.tableLayoutPanel1_Paint);
            // 
            // tableLayoutPanel2
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(55)))), ((int)(((byte)(129)))), ((int)(((byte)(175)))));
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnCount = 2;
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1, 1, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox2, 0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.Name = "tableLayoutPanel2";
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowCount = 1;
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 64F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 64);
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.TabIndex = 0;
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.mdown);
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(397, 3);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 58);
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // pictureBox2
            // 
            this.pictureBox2.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
            this.pictureBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 7);
            this.pictureBox2.Name = "pictureBox2";
            this.pictureBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
            this.pictureBox2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.pictureBox2.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // tableLayoutPanel3
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel3.ColumnCount = 1;
            this.tableLayoutPanel3.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(this.panel1, 0, 1);
            this.tableLayoutPanel3.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.tableLayoutPanel3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 448);
            this.tableLayoutPanel3.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel3.Name = "tableLayoutPanel3";
            this.tableLayoutPanel3.RowCount = 2;
            this.tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 80F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 20F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 52);
            this.tableLayoutPanel3.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(55)))), ((int)(((byte)(129)))), ((int)(((byte)(175)))));
            this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 41);
            this.panel1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 11);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // panel2
            // 
            this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 67);
            this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
            this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
            this.panel2.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 500);
            this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.mdown);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).EndInit();
            this.tableLayoutPanel3.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;
    }
}
```

### Child

**.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form4 : WindowsFormsApplication3.Form1
    {
        public Form4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**.Designer.cs**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    partial class Form4
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Designervariable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Verwendete Ressourcen bereinigen.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">True, wenn verwaltete Ressourcen gelöscht werden sollen; andernfalls False.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Vom Windows Form-Designer generierter Code

        /// <summary>
        /// Erforderliche Methode für die Designerunterstützung.
        /// Der Inhalt der Methode darf nicht mit dem Code-Editor geändert werden.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 49);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 30);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // Form4
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 500);
            this.Name = "Form4";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        public System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd avoid form inheritance like this. It's ok to create custom form and use it as a parent. Or utilize `UserControl`s to compose comprehensive UI. Having parent form with `InitializeComponent()` seems to be a [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/826425/1997232) (try to call base constructor from child form constructor).

Comment: didn't I do exactly that: `create custom form and use it as a parent` ?

Comment: For me *custom* control is the one which doesn't have designer parts (compare to simply *inherited* control). Have you tried to add `: base()` to your child constructor?

Comment: The base class controls are private, that stops you from modifying their properties in the derived class.  Change their Modifiers property to Protected.  Do beware that there is little you can do with a TableLayoutPanel, its designer is always disabled in a derived class.

Comment: @Sinatr no change - still not working

Comment: @HansPassant Still cant change anything in the designer

Comment: That's a pretty vague complaint, "it doesn't work" never helps us help you.  But I warned you about TLP, its designer isn't good enough to work in a derived form.  There is very little practical you can do about that, creating your own designer is a *lot* of work.

Comment: @HansPassant I had not read your comment carefully (Had missed the last part), SO I posted the comment and the answer for OP. I removed the answer and the comment to prevent a misunderstanding :)

Comment: **Look at this question for the Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38594178/cant-make-changes-in-inherited-child-windows-form-visual-basic**