# Designer does not accept Changes in inherited/child Windows Form (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, windows, winforms, visual-studio, inheritance

I have an template Windows Form and an child Form which Inherits the template.

But I cannot make any Changes in the Designer of the child.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

### Template

**.vb**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private isMouseDown As Boolean = False
    Private mouseOffset As Point

    ' Left mouse button pressed
    Private Sub Move_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel2.MouseDown, PictureBox2.MouseDown, PictureBox1.MouseDown
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            ' Get the new position
            Dim mouseRelative As Point = Me.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
            mouseOffset = New Point(-mouseRelative.X, -mouseRelative.Y)
            ' Set that left button is pressed
            isMouseDown = True
        End If
    End Sub

    ' MouseMove used to check if mouse cursor is moving
    Private Sub Move_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel2.MouseMove, PictureBox2.MouseMove, PictureBox1.MouseMove
        If isMouseDown Then
            Dim mousePos As Point = Control.MousePosition
            ' Get the new form position
            mousePos.Offset(mouseOffset.X, mouseOffset.Y)
            Me.Location = mousePos
        End If
    End Sub

    ' Left mouse button released, form should stop moving
    Private Sub Move_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel2.MouseUp, PictureBox2.MouseUp, PictureBox1.MouseUp
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            isMouseDown = False
        End If
    End Sub


End Class
```

**.Designer.vb**

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Das Formular überschreibt den Löschvorgang, um die Komponentenliste zu bereinigen.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Wird vom Windows Form-Designer benötigt.
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'Hinweis: Die folgende Prozedur ist für den Windows Form-Designer erforderlich.
    'Das Bearbeiten ist mit dem Windows Form-Designer möglich.  
    'Das Bearbeiten mit dem Code-Editor ist nicht möglich.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Dim Panel1 As System.Windows.Forms.Panel
        Dim TableLayoutPanel1 As System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
        Me.Panel2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
        Me.Panel3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2 = New System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel()
        Me.PictureBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
        Me.PictureBox2 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
        Panel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
        TableLayoutPanel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel()
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2.SuspendLayout()
        TableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout()
        CType(Me.PictureBox1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox2, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Panel2
        '
        Me.Panel2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(55, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(129, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(175, Byte), Integer))
        Me.Panel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
        Me.Panel2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 343)
        Me.Panel2.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
        Me.Panel2.Name = "Panel2"
        Me.Panel2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(534, 19)
        Me.Panel2.TabIndex = 1
        '
        'Panel3
        '
        Me.Panel3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(193, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(193, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(193, Byte), Integer))
        Me.Panel3.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
        Me.Panel3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 329)
        Me.Panel3.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
        Me.Panel3.Name = "Panel3"
        Me.Panel3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(534, 14)
        Me.Panel3.TabIndex = 2
        '
        'TableLayoutPanel2
        '
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(55, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(129, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(175, Byte), Integer))
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2.ColumnCount = 2
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50.0!))
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50.0!))
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox1, 0, 0)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox2, 1, 0)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2.Name = "TableLayoutPanel2"
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2.RowCount = 1
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50.0!))
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(534, 63)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2.TabIndex = 4
        '
        'Panel1
        '
        Panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
        Panel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 63)
        Panel1.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
        Panel1.Name = "Panel1"
        Panel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(534, 266)
        Panel1.TabIndex = 5
        '
        'TableLayoutPanel1
        '
        TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 1
        TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100.0!))
        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Panel1, 0, 1)
        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.Panel2, 0, 3)
        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.Panel3, 0, 2)
        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.TableLayoutPanel2, 0, 0)
        TableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
        TableLayoutPanel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        TableLayoutPanel1.Name = "TableLayoutPanel1"
        TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 4
        TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 17.5!))
        TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 73.5!))
        TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 4.0!))
        TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 5.0!))
        TableLayoutPanel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(534, 362)
        TableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'PictureBox1
        '
        Me.PictureBox1.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left
        Me.PictureBox1.Image = Global.WindowsApplication2.My.Resources.Resources.Logo
        Me.PictureBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 3)
        Me.PictureBox1.Name = "PictureBox1"
        Me.PictureBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(261, 57)
        Me.PictureBox1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.PictureBox1.TabStop = False
        '
        'PictureBox2
        '
        Me.PictureBox2.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right
        Me.PictureBox2.Image = Global.WindowsApplication2.My.Resources.Resources.Image
        Me.PictureBox2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(355, 6)
        Me.PictureBox2.Name = "PictureBox2"
        Me.PictureBox2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(176, 50)
        Me.PictureBox2.TabIndex = 1
        Me.PictureBox2.TabStop = False
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(534, 362)
        Me.Controls.Add(TableLayoutPanel1)
        Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        Me.TableLayoutPanel2.ResumeLayout(False)
        TableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(False)
        CType(Me.PictureBox1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.PictureBox2, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents Panel2 As Panel
    Friend WithEvents Panel3 As Panel
    Friend WithEvents TableLayoutPanel2 As TableLayoutPanel
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox1 As PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox2 As PictureBox
End Class
```

### Child

**.vb**

```
Public Class Form2
    Inherits WindowsApplication2.Form1


End Class
```

**.Designer.vb**

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form2
    Inherits WindowsApplication2.Form1

    'Das Formular überschreibt den Löschvorgang, um die Komponentenliste zu bereinigen.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

    'Wird vom Windows Form-Designer benötigt.
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'Hinweis: Die folgende Prozedur ist für den Windows Form-Designer erforderlich.
    'Das Bearbeiten ist mit dem Windows Form-Designer möglich.  
    'Das Bearbeiten mit dem Code-Editor ist nicht möglich.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Form2
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(534, 362)
        Me.Name = "Form2"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub

End Class
```

### Screenshots

[Template Document Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr5cl.png)

[Child Document Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHEVg.png)

[TableLayoutPanel1(root element in template) settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuBWZ.png)

[Panel1(main content element in template) settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7DbT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Look at this question for the Solution: [Cant make Changes in inherited/child Windows Form (Visual Basic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38594178/cant-make-changes-in-inherited-child-windows-form-visual-basic)**

Answer (score -1):

You should buy Visual Studio. The Community Edition of Visual Studio has errors with what you want to do, as far as I know there aren't any fixes (yet?).